# Create JSON object in Ionic SQLite

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am a beginner in Ionic. So, I want to convert JSON string to JSON object in ionic and to access JSON in html page.

controller.js

```
app.controller('OilTrackerListingCntrl', function($scope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite) 
{
$scope.pTrackerData = '';
$cordovaSQLite.execute(dbApp, "SELECT TOTAL_KM, SERVICE_DATE, AMOUNT_PAID, NEXT_SERVICE_DATE FROM OIL_TRACKER")
                .then(
                    function(res) {
                        $ionicLoading.hide();
                        if (res.rows.length > 0) {


                            for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {

                                var varTrackerData = new TrackerData(res.rows.item(i).TOTAL_KM, res.rows.item(i).SERVICE_DATE, res.rows.item(i).AMOUNT_PAID, res.rows.item(i).NEXT_SERVICE_DATE);
                                SelectedTracker.push(varTrackerData);   
                            }
                            var d = JSON.stringify(SelectedTracker);
                            alert(d);
                            $scope.pTrackerData = d;
                            alert($scope.pTrackerData);
                        } else {
                            alert('Not getting');
                        }
                    },
                    function(error) {
                        alert("Error on loading: " + error.message);
                    }
                );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  var d = JSON.stringify(SelectedTracker);    

   alert(d);  

    $scope.pTrackerData = JSON.parse(d);  

   $scope.pTrackerData = JSON.parse(d);   

 alert($scope.pTrackerData);
```